# Not enough disk space!

Tags: nvidia-geforce

I'm running Ubuntu in a dual boot with Windows 10. I wanted to install Counter strike Global offensive on Ubuntu, but it's not letting me because it's telling me "Not enough space...".

Is there any way I can add more space so that I can install it? I only have 6.8GB and the game itself has 13GB. I have tried reinstalling Ubuntu by using USB Boot. I have Ubuntu 16.04 and I'm new to all this. I don't really know much about it.

[image: installing counter strike on ubuntu]

Comment: Buy a larger hard drive. What else can I say? What, do you think that disk space can just pop up into existence out of thin air?

Comment: To see if what you're asking is even possible, please post a screenshot of GParted showing the disk you have Ubuntu installed on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are physically out of disc space. As I see it you have two options.

Make the windows partition smaller then increase your Linux partition.
[Example](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25221/how-to-shrink-windows-partition-with-unmovable-files-in-dual-boot-installation) there are main examples on here about this and on the internet.

Or

Buy a larger disk and or second disk